# Change Subsite URL in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, jsom

I have a subsite called blogsite and the URL looks like this: `http://abc/sites/SiteCollection/blogsite`

I changed the URL by mistake as `Home.aspx` by navigating to the URL `blogsite/_layouts/15/prjsetng.aspx`.

The subsite URL is now `http://abc/sites/SiteCollection/Home.aspx`

But when i navigate to the site its not working. How can i update the subsite URL using javascript object model?

Answer (score 0):

Please use [SP.Web.serverRelativeUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/jj246457.aspx) for setting the SubSite url via JSOM.